# No. of samplers showing more in listner than defined in Thread

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

[image]In thread I have mentioned 2 thread means 2 users but when I run my test in listner it shows 16 Samples.

Why its behaving like this?

Please check the below attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a Stepup thread group, which is used for Stress test. This thread group is time based so if you say hold 2 users for 5 seconds, it will keep 2 users active for that time frame irrespective of samples it has to create.

hope this will help.[image]

Comment: is it possible to use Stepup thread group and each user hit each sampler only once?

Comment: keep your settings as per the screen shot attached